# homepage url changed to /STORECODE/cms/index/index after 1.9.2.4 upgrade

Tags: magento-1.9, url, upgrade, layered-navigation, ce-1.9.2.4

After I did an upgrade to latest magento CE version 1.9.2.4, I noticed 2 weird changes:

frontend: home page url was changed to /STORECODE/cms/index/index

backend: once an admin user logged in, he will face 404 error, the url is admin/index/noRoute

I've no conflicts. All modules have been updated to the new routing. Other admin functions are working and frontend pages are working as expected too.

[image: this redirection is happening on php level]

Comment: what was your prior version? and how did you update? via supee or reinstall?

Comment: older version was 1.9.0.1 and I updated via full reinstall then I patched the local/community modules

Comment: then there may be store view code in url be active in the backend. if you disable this option again, all should be fine. if it is disabled already, enable it, save, disable it and save again.

Comment: What do you mean with a full install? Did you import your database? This is a setting in the database, so in case you reset your database it is possible that "include store code in URL" can be on now.

Comment: @Michael , I tried to  disable it and reenabled it but with no luck

Comment: @Alex no i meant a full copy of M1.9.2.4 php files and I'm already have storcode in url enabled

Comment: if you reENabled it, its ok that you got the /en/ in the url. Besides, did you clear any kind of cache like Magentos one, redus, varnish, apc,xcache and so on?

Comment: yes I did , I flush all redis

Comment: So your Problem is the CMS/index/index while you expect just /store/ ? Might be the rewrite index. Did you try to rebuild it?

Comment: @Alex   thanks for your time , I've found out the root cause of it below

Answer (score 1):

turned out the issue is caused by manadev layered navigation seo module , it has a custom router

> app/code/local/Mana/Seo/Router.php

the  lines 110 - 113 was creating the redirect based on  of options was : **Redirect To Same Page With Correct Parameter Order**  and the **[docs](http://www.manadev.com/user-guides/seo-layered-navigation-plus/seo---search-engine-optimization-settings)** recommend to set it to yes , setting it to no solved the issues on frontend & backend

seems to be a bug related to this module , I've reported it back to them ,

**its not related to magento upgrade**